# How to change mapType of Google Maps dynamically?

Tags: google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have set up the Google maps in my jetpack compose project. It's working fine i have set the intial mapType to `MapType.HYBRID`. But there is a paramtere passed in the composable function called `mapType`. I want to update the mapType of Google Map whenever the newvalue of paramtere is changed. Here is my code ->

```
@Composable
fun MapMeasurementCompactScreen(
    mapType: MapType
) {

    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(LatLng(1.35, 103.87), 10f)
    }

    val properties by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            MapProperties(
                isMyLocationEnabled = true,
                mapType = MapType.NORMAL // here i want to use the parmater so it chnages the type of map dynamically
            )
        )
    }

    Box {

        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
            properties = properties,
            onMyLocationClick = {
                cameraPositionState.position =
                    CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude), 10f)
            }
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you use the `by` keyword, you can change `val` to `var` like this:

```
var properties by remember {
    mutableStateOf(
        MapProperties(
            isMyLocationEnabled = true,
            mapType = MapType.NORMAL
        )
    )
}
```

Then, when you want to change the properties, simply do

```
properties = properties.copy(mapType = MapType.TERRAIN)  // set new MapType
```

Jetpack Compose will then pick up the changes and will recompose accordingly.